# Video Streaming issues with Explorer 9

Tags: video, stream, internet-explorer-9

So, I've been working on two websites (still relatively new to web design and coding).  I work on a Mac on Dreamweaver.  Tested the sites on Safari, Firefox, and Chrome, all looking good.  Didn't have access to a PC, but Dreamweaver said there was no browser conflict for Explorer.  So great, right?

Then a few days ago I started working in an office with PCs and running Explorer 9.  Testing my sites out there, I noticed two problems:

1. On my front page (www.lesbianzombies.com) I have an opening video (7-8 secs) on auto playback, no controls.  For some reason on Explorer - it plays the video, but the video is kicked out of the div/frame, and covers the menu for the rest of the page.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is doing this in explorer (tried changing css, but nothing working).
2. At the same time, my video on my other pages that are NOT autoplay, and DO have controls - the video doesn't play - there is not even an option to try to play on Explorer.  Only the posters are shown.  (Example: www.bigthingsproductions.com/projects.html)

In my code I'm using HTML5 video object.  I have mp4 option, then webm, then ogg.  Then I have a flash option if those don't work, aren't available.  I thought I had covered my bases.

I have not been able to test how the sites behave in Explorer 7 or 8.  So I'd be curious to know if it's only a v9 issue.  Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Below is the code I'm using for the front page where the video is playing out-of-frame:

```
<div id="main">
      <div id="homeMain">

       <video id="OpenVideo" width="796" height="546" poster="QueenHome.jpg" autoplay />
  <source src="loading.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="loading.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source src="loading.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
  <!-- Non HTML5 fallback -->
  <object width="796" height="546" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf"> 
  <param name="movie" value="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf"></param>
  <param name="flashvars" value="src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lesbianzombies.com%2FQueenFront_flash.mp4&controlBarMode=none&poster=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lesbianzombies.com%2Fimages%2FQueenFront.jpg&playButtonOverlay=false&autoPlay=true"></param>
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false"></param>
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
  <img src="images/QueenHome.jpg" alt="No video supported." title="No video supported." />
  </object>
  <!-- End Non HTML5 fallback -->
</video>

      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/videoHandler.js"></script>
  <!-- InstanceEndEditable --><!-- End main -->
```

Also, the pertinent css:

```
#main #homeMain {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Jave, did you ever find a solution? I'm facing similar problems using the FlashMediaPlayback.swf player hosted on adobe.com.